# Private Policy links dont work google sigin library android

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

I have sign-with-google implemented in my app with https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/

I cannot open a link to google's privacy policy from a popup from this library

any magicians or googlers here that might help?
[image]